# Neovim interpolation gives E15 "Invalid Expression"

Tags: neovim

According to this:
https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#interpolated-string

I should be able to do this:

`:echo $"The square root of 9 is {sqrt(9)}"`

But that gives me:

`E15: Invalid expression: $"The square root of 9 is {sqrt(9)}"`

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation are supported in Vim 9.0 but not in Neovim 0.9.5

It seems to have been implemented on September 2019 on Vim (see issue [#4491](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4491)) but not merged yet in Neovim 0.9.5

But it works fine in the nightly build of Neovim 0.10

Comment: Hm, so is  `https://neovim.io/doc` really docu for vim?  And not neovim?

Comment: It is the doc of Neovim trunk not the doc of Neovim stable I believe.